# Knockout.js breaks in /checkout in my theme

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento2.2, knockoutjs, magento-2.2.1

I use **magento 2.2.1** with a **purchased template** and on "Enable Onepage Checkout" option enabled.

The problem is the template is broken by almost everywhere and the author is irresponsible (I sent tickets but he doesn't help me), I have already fixed many problems but I am stuck in this.

When you go to **Checkout page**, **Knockout.js** breaks with the following error:

[image: Error javascript]

I have been reviewing and I don't give with the solution, in the template of magento doesn't happen.

Can someone give me an indication of what to check?

Comment: isLoading method is undefined, Check inside html template where it's bind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need are.

1. Where html file call **blockLoader** in your checkout html page?
2. Where js component file binds to this html text.
3. Have you check **onepage.phtml** of that theme with default magento module **Magento_Checkout/templates/onepage.phtml** did you saw this code

Code:

```
<script>
        require([
            'mage/url',
            'Magento_Ui/js/block-loader'
        ], function(url, blockLoader) {
            blockLoader("<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getViewFileUrl('images/loader-1.gif'); ?>");
            return url.setBaseUrl('<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getBaseUrl();?>');
        })
    </script>
```

if not define this to that **phtml** file

Comment: the code is already in the Magento_Checkout/templates/onepage.phtml: [link](https://imgur.com/wv5OZU7).

Comment: Then where your html called function **blockLoader** ??

Comment: I have been reviewing each of the calls to the function and I have found one that was not necessary, I have deleted it and I have solved it, thank you.